# How can I choose a menu item from dropdown menu using AppleScript (Big Sur OS)

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-catalina, macos-big-sur

For Catalina I would only do something like this in Preview

```
click pop up button 3
click menu item "Study Edge" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
```

But for Big Sur this no longer works :(

After adding splitter group which is now needed for Big Sur my code looks as follows:

```
tell sheet 1
    tell splitter group 1
        click pop up button 3
        click menu item "Study Edge" of menu 1 of pop up button 3
    end tell
    click menu button "PDF"
    repeat until exists menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
        delay 0.02
    end repeat
    click menu item "Save as PDF" of menu 1 of menu button "PDF"
end tell
```

But it is not able to find the menu item "Study Edge"

[image]

Comment: In your previous question your said it was "My Customized Size" and now you are saying it's "Customized Size", so which is it? That said, whatever you name it originally it has changed to show differently in **macOS Big Sur** in that it also adds the **Paper Size:** settings to the _name_, e.g. `click menu item "My Customized Size 8.50 by 11.00 inches" of menu 1 of pop up button 3 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Preview"`

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. The name doesn't really matter since it is an arbitrary name I gave. I tried this and still doesn't work

Comment: The _menu item_ is not `"Study Edge"`, it's: `"Study Edge 8.50 by 11.00 inches"`

Comment: Thank you!!! You da best :)